# Magento - Changing Footer

Tags: magento, layout, content-management-system, block, footer

is it possible to change the footer of a category page in Magento?
We're using the version 1.7.0.2

What we want:
We need the footer to be floating on the category pages and to be sticky on any other pages.
The sticky part and the floating part is not the problem.

We need to figure out, how to "assign" the floating footer just to the footer on the category page.

This hasn't worked:

```
<default>
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column-float.phtml</template>
    </action>
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer-float.phtml" />
     </reference>  
 </default>
```

Can you give me a hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you what you want:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column-float.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer-float.phtml" />
     </reference>  
 </catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column-float.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer-float.phtml" />
     </reference>  
 </catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: Just one more question: Unfortunately this won't work now: 
<footer class="main">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?>
</footer>
Seems that cms_footer_links isn't available but we have declared it in  the cms.xml - What do we have to change?